# Query records with their parent record name and their related records

Tags: soql

I'm trying to query records with their parent record name and their related records.
This is my query:

> SELECT Id, Name, Record_Type_Name__c,
>   **Engagement_Model__r.Name**, (SELECT Contained_Product__r.Id,
>   Contained_Product__r.ProductCode FROM Contained_Products__r) FROM
>   Product2 WHERE Record_Type_Name__c = 'Subscription_Package'

My problem is with the **Engagement_Model__r.Name**, the query does not return it at all.
Instead it returns Engagement_Model__c.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Salesforce just posted this timely [blog post on querying relationships in SOQL](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/05/basic-soql-relationship-queries.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try using this as your query in Developer Console:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Record_Type_Name__c, (SELECT Name FROM Engagement_Model__r) , (SELECT Contained_Product__r.Id, Contained_Product__r.ProductCode FROM Contained_Products__r) FROM Product2 WHERE Record_Type_Name__c = 'Subscription_Package'
```

Please refer to this link for a similar issue/fix:

```
http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Problem-with-SOQL-relationship-queries/m-p/62895#M16379
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what I get when I try your query: Didn't understand relationship 'Engagement_Model__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing this query in the Developer's Console which for some reason does not return the expected result. When testing the same query in the Workbench it works fine...

Comment: That's good - it should work - maybe a quirk of the Developer Console. Are you on a Summer '13 sandbox?

Comment: Still Spring 13

Comment: You might try creating the query in Ajax Tools or Force.com Explorer to see if it shows a different relationship from Product2 to engagement_model__c/engagement_model__r.Name.

Answer (score 0):

That should work. Obviously those are custom lookup fields on your Product2 so I can't try that query myself. Are you sure that there is a value in engagement_model__c lookup?
What do you get for this:

```
List<Product2> prods = [SELECT Id, Name, Record_Type_Name__c, Engagement_Model__r.Name, (SELECT Contained_Product__r.Id, Contained_Product__r.ProductCode FROM Contained_Products__r) FROM Product2 WHERE Record_Type_Name__c = 'Subscription_Package'];
System.debug(prods[0].engagement_model__r.name);
```